# gVim 起動時の配色を指定のカラースキームに設定したい

Tags: vim

Windows 10 上でKaoriya製の最新のgvimを使いはじめた初心者です。

colorscheme molokaiを.vimrcに書いているのに起動時には反映されず、起動後 `:colorscheme molokai` と入力しないと変わってくれません。

ちなみに dein.toml には以下の内容を記入済みです。

```
[[plugins]]
repo = 'tomasr/molokai'
```

詳しい方、教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `.gvimrc`にcolorshcemeの設定を書いてもダメですか？

Comment: `.gvimrc`がなかったので作って中にcolorschemeの設定を書いたら行けました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみに`.gvimrc`は普通に拡張子いじったりする方法では作れずコマンドプロンプトから`vim .gvimrc`で保存しました。

Comment: すみません、Windows(Kaoriya)版だと設定ファイルは`_vimrc`と`_gvimrc`でしたね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(コメント欄でのやり取りより)
gVim利用時の設定は`.vimrc`ではなく、`.gvimrc`にcolorschemeに関する記述を追記してみてください。

なお、Windows(Kaoriya)版だと設定ファイルは`_vimrc`と`_gvimrc`になります。

Comment: vimとgvim両方で使いたいものは`.vimrc`に、gvimのみで使うものは`.gvimrc`にというわけではないのですね。

Comment: 基本的な設定は`.vimrc`からも引き継ぐのですが、今回のcolorscheme含めGUI周りの設定は`.gvimrc`への記述が必要、という一定のルールがあります(覚えるのが大変ですが)。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。